# angular 6:npm module awesome-phonenumber not validating nigeria new phone number series

Tags: angular

I am using awesome-phonenumber node module in my current project and validating phone numbers with this plugin

though nowadays I am facing issues after new phone number series are introduced in a particular region.

phone number +234801*****54 is not being validated, hence phone number is correct

I have tried updating npm module **awesome-phonenumber** to the latest version but that also does not work.

> "awesome-phonenumber": "^2.24.0"

Code snapshot:

```
 static phnValidate(c: FormControl): ValidationErrors {
const num = c.value;
let isValid = false;
const pn = new awesomePhonenumber(num != null ? num : '+91');

if (pn.isValid() && pn.isMobile()) {
  isValid = true
}
const message = {
  'phoneNumber': {
    'message': 'Phone Number is not valid'
  }
};
return isValid ? null : message;
```

}

error Screenshots:

[invalid phone number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDf6l.png)

[valid phone number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb5U0.png)

[github issue link](https://github.com/grantila/awesome-phonenumber/issues/46)

[npm module link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awesome-phonenumber)

Answer (score 0):

Awesome-phonenumber knows a set of pattern for new phonenumbers. If the new type of numbers from Nigeria You can basically only wait until Google (hence they are using a library form Google) recognize it. May be you can write an Issue or Pull-Request here: 
https://github.com/google/libphonenumber.

Meanwhile you can only write your own Check for this type of numbers:

```
...
const pn = new awesomePhonenumber(num != null ? num : '+91');

if (pn.isValid() && pn.isMobile()) {
  isValid = true
}

if (! isValid && /^([a-z0-9]{10,})$/.test(num)) {
  isValid = true
}
```

`^([a-z0-9]{10,})` **is just an example**. You have a to write a RegEx according to the new type of numbers.